# How to properly implement waiting of async computations?

Tags: performance, theory

i have some little trouble and i am asking for hint. I am on Windows platform, doing calculations in a following manner:

```
int input = 0;
int output; // junk bytes here
while(true) {
    async_enqueue_upload(input); // completes instantly, but transfer will take 10us
    async_enqueue_calculate(); // completes instantly, but computation will take 80us
    async_enqueue_download(output); // completes instantly, but transfer will take 10us
    sync_wait_finish(); // must wait while output is fully calculated, and there is no junk
    input = process(output); // i cannot launch next step without doing it on the host.
}
```

I am asking about wait_finish() thing. I must wait all devices to finish, to combine all results and somehow process the data and upload a new portion, that is based on a previous computation step. I need to sync data in between each step, so i can't parallelize steps. I know, this is not quite performant case. So lets proceed to question.

I have 2 ways of checking completion, within wait_finish(). First is to put thread to sleep until it wakes up by completion event:

```
while( !is_completed() )
    Sleep(1);
```

It has very low performance, because actual calculation, to say, takes 100us, and minimal Windows sheduler timestep is 1ms, so it gives unsuitable 10x lower performance.

Second way is to check completion in empty infinite loop:

```
while( !is_completed() )
    {} // do_nothing();
```

It has 10x good computation performance. But it is also unsuitable solution, because it makes full cpu core utilisation usage, with absolutely useless work. How to make cpu "sleep" exactly time i needed? (Each step has equal amount of work)

How this case is usually solved, when amount of calculation time is too big for active spin-wait, but is too small compared to sheduler timestep? Also related subquestion - how to do that on linux?

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, i have succeeded in finding answer on my own. In short words - i should use linux for that.

And my investigation shows following. On windows there is hidden function in ntdll, `NtDelayExecution()`. It is not exposed through SDK, but can be loaded in a following manner:

```
static int(__stdcall *NtDelayExecution)(BOOL Alertable, PLARGE_INTEGER DelayInterval) = (int(__stdcall*)(BOOL, PLARGE_INTEGER)) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleW(L"ntdll.dll"), "NtDelayExecution");
```

It allows to set sleep intervals in 100ns periods. However, even that not worked well, as shown in a following benchmark:

```
SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS); // requires Admin privellegies
SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);
uint64_t hpf = qpf(); // QueryPerformanceFrequency()
uint64_t s0 = qpc(); // QueryPerformanceCounter()
uint64_t n = 0;
while (1) {     
    sleep_precise(1); // NtDelayExecution(-1); waits one 100-nanosecond interval
    auto s1 = qpc();
    n++;
    auto passed = s1 - s0;
    if (passed >= hpf) {
        std::cout << "freq=" << (n * hpf / passed) << " hz\n";
        s0 = s1;
        n = 0;
    }
}
```

That yields something less than just 2000 hz loop rate, and result varies from string to string. That led me towards windows thread switching sheduler, which is totally not suited for real time tasks. And its minimum interval of 0.5ms (+overhead). Btw, does anyone knows on how to tune that value?

And next was linux question, and what does it can? So i've built custom tiny kernel 4.14 with means of [buildroot](https://buildroot.org/), and tested that benchmark code there. I replaced `qpc()` to return `clock_gettime()` data, with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` clock, and `qpf()` just returns number of nanoseconds in a second and `sleep_precise()` just called `clock_nanosleep()`. I was failed to find out what is the difference between `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` and `CLOCK_REALTIME`.

And i was quite surprised, getting whooping 18.4khz frequency just out of the box, and that was quite stable. While i tested several intervals, i found that i can set the loop to almost any frequency up to 18.4khz, but also that actual measured wait time results differs to 1.6 times of what i asked. For example if i ask to sleep 100 us it actually sleeps for ~160 us, giving ~6.25 khz frequency. Nothing else is going on the system, just kernel, busybox and this test. I am not an experience linux user, and i am still wondering how can i tune this to be more real-time and deterministic. Can i push that frequency maximum even more?